Using newton's method to approximate sqrt of an integer, ZeroDivisionError

Sqrt(x)

Given a non-negative integer x, return the square root of x rounded down to the nearest integer. The returned integer should be non-negative as well.
You must not use any built-in exponent function or operator.
For example, do not use pow(x, 0.5) in c++ or x ** 0.5 in python.
Example 1:
Input: x = 4
Output: 2
Explanation: The square root of 4 is 2, so we return 2.
Example 2:
Input: x = 8
Output: 2
Explanation: The square root of 8 is 2.82842..., and since we round it down to the nearest integer, 2 is returned.
when x = 8
I expected to the function to return 2, since int(y) rounds down the number, but I got a ZeroDivisionError on line  (estimate = (1/2)*(estimate+(x/estimate)). This is an easy leetcode problem #69 sqrt(x)
Here is my code which I ran on leetcode:
def mySqrt(self, x):
    estimate= 1 + ((x-1)//2)
    difference = abs(x-(estimate*estimate))
    tolerance = .005
    while difference  > tolerance:
        estimate = (1/2)*(estimate+(x/estimate))
        difference  = abs((x-(estimate*estimate)))
    return int(estimate)`

Runtime Error
ZeroDivisionError: integer division or modulo by zero
    estimate = (1/2)*(estimate+(x/estimate))
Line 8 in mySqrt (Solution.py)
    ret = Solution().mySqrt(param_1)
Line 29 in _driver (Solution.py)
    _driver()
Line 39 in <module> (Solution.py)


The point of leetcode is you learn by solving the problem yourself. Please try to debug and fix the error yourself before you just give up and ask others to do your homework for you.

Also, this is not the place to search for help, if you get stuck with leetcode problems.

What Python version is Leetcode using?  This code works just fine with Python 3, but would fail under Python 2  because 1/2 evaluates to zero.

If you're calculating an integer square root, then you shouldn't be using floating point at all.  But you are using floating point.  That's a big problem right there.  You're trying to compute a floating square root, then convert the result to an integer.  Instead, keep it as an integer the entire way through.  It's not hard.

Leetcode allows you to choose between different python versions.
I chose python 2 to write my solution in. In python 2  1/2  and 1//2 evaluates to 0, this is called integer division which preserves type and rounds the result down to the nearest integer. When I changed to python 3, the solution worked and there was no division by zero error since 1/2 evaluated to 0.5, this is called real division(promoting integer to a floating value).
The lesson learned was to debug using the same version of whatever language you are programming in, and I learned about promotion of integer to a floating value. Lastly, I should have kept the number as integer the entire way instead of converting my result to integer after using floating point. Also, I could have figured it out if I thought about it longer. I will research more before posting, Thank you for all the help!
